# Android Intent extras

Tags: android, android-intent

I am completely lost on this one. I am new to Android Dev and really am stumped by this one.

I got an application that loads a listview with all the customers names and ID's
I am able to get the ID of the customer. I try to pass the intent

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "VIPID";
...
Intent intent = new Intent(ManageVIPCustomers.this, Contact.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, itemString);
                startActivity(intent);
```

ManageVIPCustomers is the sending activity and Contact is the receiving. 
Contacts receiving command is:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String VIPString = intent.getStringExtra(ManageVIPCustomers.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Everything Compiles fine, but upon click it says the app has been stopped.

My (partial)Manifest is below:

```
    <activity
            android:name=".ManageVIPCustomers"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_manage_vipcustomers" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<activity
            android:name=".Contact"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Any help would be great

EDIT:
LogCat below:

```
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904): Process: edu.gatech.seclass.project2, PID: 1904
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{edu.gatech.seclass.project2/edu.gatech.seclass.project2.Contact}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1884)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at edu.gatech.seclass.project2.Contact.<init>(Contact.java:29)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2101)
11-03 01:33:03.719: E/AndroidRuntime(1904):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post your log cat when the error happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the Intent or its extras. Your second Activity is calling `findViewById` in its constructor before you have set the content view for the Activity, probably because you are declaring something like this outside of any method:

```
View someView = findViewById(R.id.some_id);
```

Assignments outside of constructors or methods are run at the time the object is created. This is not the correct time to call `findViewById`. You need to declare the view only and call `findViewById` AFTER you have set the content view:

```
View someView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);
    someView = findViewById(R.id.some_id);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wow I feel really dumb. Thought that little trick would end up saving time by declaring the textviews outside of a function! Thank you If I had enough Rep I would up-vote the response, but I greatly appreciate it!